# Calendar Roll will it wrap around a given year, month, etc?

Tags: java, calendar, utility

So let's say I have this code:

```
//someParameterizedDate = New Years Eve 2011
Calendar cal = new GregorianCalendar();
cal.setTime(someParameterizedDate);
cal.roll(Calendar.DAY_OF_YEAR, 1);
```

Will the calendar now be equal to january 1, 2012? I found all the JavaDocs a little confusing.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[java.util.Calendar](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html)

> roll(f, delta) adds delta to field f without changing larger fields.
>   This is equivalent to calling add(f, delta) with the following
>   adjustment:
>
> Roll rule. Larger fields are unchanged after the call. A larger field
>   represents a larger unit of time. DAY_OF_MONTH is a larger field than
>   HOUR.

You roll with `DAY_OF_YEAR` which means it will not affect `MONTH` or `YEAR` which are larger units

So basically, you should get you to December 1st 2011

You can use `add` if you want it to go to January 1st 2012